# Intellij 2016 Multiple tabs for Tool window

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 2016.3.3 and I want my `Run` and `Messages` window to be switchable like tabs. Right now I have them in split mode as shown below:

[image]

Can this be changed to tabs in tool window such that whichever tab I click that covers the whole area ? Split mode does not suit me.

**Update:**
When click on the upper right wheel , these are the options I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay , I found the solution. All, we had to do was to go to `View -> Tool buttons` and activate it. See the image below :

[image]

and now if you look at bottom and right , we will see tabs for all possible tool windows. Have a  look at figure below:

[image]

Now, we can simply click and select the tab we want. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can turnoff split mode in tab options:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any option ` Show Views as Tabs `

Comment: The screenshot is from IU-14.1.7.

Comment: I am using 2016